# Can I take advantage of Apple's push notification servers for an instant messaging app?

Tags: ios, instant-messaging

I am trying to create an instant messaging app for iOS devices. Is it possible to send the messages through the same Apple server as push notifications. Also, I was told jabber was a possibility as well. Does anyone know anything about either of these questions and/or know of any tutorials of how to implement either?

Answer (score 0):

Apple's iMessage uses their push notification, so that should indeed work. It obviously won't work on different phones, e.g. Android. iOS limits what you can do in the background, so jabber may not work when in the background. Apple's push notification will work even if your app isn't running.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious about the same thing. I did look into XMPP (aka Jabber) but couldn't quite figure out how to use an XMPP server and the [XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework) only for sending custom info to the device.

For using APNs as the to deliver the messages, there is a very pertinent tutorial on RayWenderlich: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3525/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-2.
Part 1 is also useful for learning how to use APNs.

Personally I'm still undecided how I'm going to implement the realtime-ish part of my app, leaning towards using APNs atm.